# PEP 8: How to name an acronym for a library named a2b?

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8

I have had created a source file named url2dictionary.py (got influenced by word2vec) and I want to import it in other scripts such as:

```
import url2dictionary as ud
```

Now, ud doesn't feel quite right as pd does for pandas, or tf for tensorflow. So I wonder what is the best way to import these kind of named libraries. Or should I name my library entirely differently from the beginning?

Comment: `url2dictionary` might be a good name for a function or a method, but not a module.

Comment: Most of these 'canonical' import abbreviations are only a convention. If your library isn't common enough to have a popular or canon import, then it doesn't really matter. I can `import pandas as pananananadas` if I want, it'll just look silly to anyone reading my code. (As long as you follow [pep guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) of course)

Comment: Go wild and `import url2dictionary as u2d`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PEP8 doesn't prescribe specifics for cases like this--Pandas and tensorflow made it an unofficial common practice to create a shorthand alias when importing their main module (e.g. `import pandas as pd`/`import tensorflow as tf`)

What you're doing is fine, I would stick with `import url2dictionary as ud`